# Обновить значение в таблице БД

Tags: android

Как обновить значение поля у записи с каким-нибудь ID?

У меня сейчас так

```
if (favorites.equals("1")) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(SlovarContract.SlovarEntry.COL_FAVORITES, "0");

    long newRowId = db.database.update(SlovarContract.SlovarEntry.TABLE1, values, SlovarContract.SlovarEntry.COL_WORD + "= ?", new String[]{word});
    favorites = "0";
    if (newRowId == -1) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Ошибка", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Удалено из избранное", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        item.setIcon(R.drawable.icon_star_white);
    }
}
```

Но мне нужно вместо SlovarContract.SlovarEntry.COL_WORD чтобы было проверка SlovarContract.SlovarEntry._ID = wordID. Т.е чтобы обновлялось у записи с _ID=wordID

Comment: db.database.update(SlovarContract.SlovarEntry.TABLE1, values , "_ID="+wordID, null);

Comment: Спасибо, сработало